# Simple differential inequality - reference request

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am looking for a reference for the following simple inequality.
Let $y \in \mathcal{C}^1[0,\infty)$ such that $$y'\leq-y.$$ Then $$y(x)\leq y(0)e^{-x}.$$

I found a [short seminar paper online](http://www.math.ubbcluj.ro/~nodeacj/download.php?f=020POPA2.pdf) which cites this (somewhat more generally) as its first Lemma and links to a book Stability Analysis of Nonlinear Systems by Lakshmikantham, Leela and Martynyuk. However, I don't have a ready access to that book so I cannot check the reference.

This might be too basic to appear in a paper, but a printed book which is available online (for free) would be perfect.

Thanks!

Comment: Google the following four words: gen lib rus ec. The put the title of your book and follow your nose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use integrating factors for that, in general the Grönwall lemma.

$$
(e^xy(x))'=e^x(y'(x)+y(x))\le 0
$$
implies
$$
e^xy(x)-e^0y(0)\le 0
$$
from where the claimed inequality easily follows.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose I should not work late into the evening. I can't believe I missed the fact that this is just a special case of Grönwall's Lemma.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
y'+y&\leq 0\\
e^{x}y'(x)+e^{x}y(x)&\leq 0\\
(y(x)e^{x})'&\leq 0, 
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x}(y(t)e^{t})'dt\leq\int_{0}^{x}0dt=0,
\end{align*}
Fundamental Theorem of Calculus gives $y(x)e^{x}-y(0)\leq 0$.